# rxjs operator which notifies one value when uptream completes

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream `myStream` which does some work but does not notify anything and, at the end of the work, `complete`s.

I am looking for an operator which can listen the `complete` of `myStream` and, at that moment, notifies a value, something like this

```
myStream.pipe(
  operatorThatNotifiesWhenUpstreamCompletes('Upstream has completed')
).subscribe(console.log)  // prints 'Upstream has completed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`defaultIfEmpty()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/defaultIfEmpty) :).